# Load and use a Service Worker in Karma test

Tags: karma-runner, travis-ci, service-worker

We want to write a [Service Worker](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/) that performs source code transformation on the loaded files. In order to test this functionality, we use Karma.

Our tests import source files, on which the source code transformation is performed. The tests only succeed if the Service Worker performs the transformation and fail when the Service Worker is not active.

Locally, we can start Karma with `singleRun: false` and watch for changed files to restart the tests. However, Service Workers are not active for the page that originally loaded them. Therefore, every test case succeeds but the first one.

However, for continuous integration, we need a single-run mode. So, our Service Worker is not active during the run of the test, which fail accordingly.
Also, two consecutive runs do not solve this issue, as Karma restarts the used browser (so we lose the Service Worker).

So, the question is, how to make the Service Worker available in the test run?
E.g., by preserving the browser instance used by karma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `self.clients.claim()` within your service worker's `activate` hander signals to the browser that you'd like your service worker to take control on the initial page load in which the service worker is first registered. You can see an example of this in action in [Service Worker Sample: Immediate Control](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/immediate-control/).

I would recommend that in the JavaScript of your controlled page, you wait for the `navigator.serviceWorker.ready` promise to resolve before running your test code. Once that promise does resolve, you'll know that there's an active service worker controlling your page. The [test for the `<platinum-sw-register>` Polymer element](https://github.com/PolymerElements/platinum-sw/blob/master/test/platinum-sw-register/index.html#L28) uses this technique.